# How To Add Custom Field In woo commerce product listing admin page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am very much new to `wordpress` and need help. Well I need to add a custom field to `woocommerce product listing page` in admin and make it work.

So where do I have to make changes in code or in admin section.I need some suggestions on how to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this link and get the accurate Ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064908/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-to-my-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-3

Comment: I looked at it,honestly i don't think i got it,an easier explanation would be better for a naive like me

Answer (score 2):

if I'm understanding you right you want to add new fields to your woocommerce products, and you want those fields to show up in the admin panel. I am working on this right now myself and I have found a few good resources.

First of all, although I can't find any documentation on them yet directly in the woocommerce API docs, there are two hooks for extending the admin panel.

- `woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs` - this allows you to insert a new tab within the admin panel. from browsing the source of various free woocommerce plugins that do this it appears that the tab format should be `<li><a href="#tab_name">Tab Name</a></li>`.
- `woocommerce_product_write_panel` - this is where the insertion of your custom panel contents would go, placed within a `<div id="#tab_name"></div>`

These are the two hooks that I have had a great deal of difficulty locating. They allow you to hook into the actual woocommerce admin area, otherwise custom fields you might add will end up in a separate panel.

For all the details on actually adding the custom fields themselves and hooking them up to the front-end, I suggest this tutorial here, which covers the basic concepts involved in adding a new meta-data field and hooking it into the product display (in this case the single-product detail view, it sounds like you want to modify them in the list view but this will show you the basic principles).

http://www.xatik.com/2013/02/06/add-custom-form-woocommerce-product/

Note: that tutorial doesn't use the woocommerce admin panel but creates its own panel, the instructions I gave above, plus this tutorial, should get you just about anywhere you need to go.

Comment: Where are the files exactly? I've been doing a find in file for `woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs` which dug up the action calls.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. These are hooks, which means you don't need to know which file WooCommerce will call them for and it also means that WooCommerce likely will feel free to move that around as needed over time since it's decoupled. If you would like to know anyway you can search the woocommerce repository on github, for example, for ```woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs``` you would get [this result](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs&ref=cmdform). But I am perhaps misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yea, that is similar to how I found the action call. Yea, sorry I only now know about hooks. I was literally looking for the function. When looking into how I can alter the functions without editing the WooCommerce files (so I can safely update the WooCommerce plugin without losing the changes), I came across hooks. So, in other words, sorry, you can ignore my original question and thanks for responding quick

Comment: No problem, I'm new to most of this myself, anyway. Whether using hooks or not the documentation often seems a bit hacky and confusing. And even though using these hooks decouples you, you end up having to read their source code to understand the context of where your code will be inserted half the time.