# How to add fields to custom post type / add custom post to another custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So the situation is following - I have defined 2 custom post types in Wordpress: Speakers and Workshops. I will use ACF plugin for fields.

And I need to configure them in such way that each Workshop can have one or multiple starting times - It can be at 12PM, 4PM or any other times or just one of previously mentioned. Each Workshop can also have one or multiple speakers. How do I create such configuration? I've read something about ACF relationship but didn't completely understand how it would work and how would I output the data in the end. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Also Speakers added to Workshops would come from previously defined Custom post type "Speakers" not from ACF fields.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already or check out the [tour].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add custom fields to my custom post type in Wordpress 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064908/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-to-my-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the multiple starting times is [The Repeater Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) a good choice, but it is part of the Pro Version.

Multiple Speakers you can handle with the [Post Object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/) field type.

Comment: And I have bought pro version so repeater will do the trick, thank you.

I used relationship field that, quote, acf website "creates a very attractive version of the post object field", yes :)